# Load Average 140% on Apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

I have the following problem, I have 120 wordpress servers on the server, on average Load Average was 3-4%, suddenly it increased to 140% and it keeps sticking all the time. I thought it was MySQL that eats the ram but it currently uses 280.3 MB. After checking, htop shows that the most burdensome server / usr / bin / httpd or apache 2.4 what can be seen in the picture, CPU usage 100%. The server has 32GB RAM and has always consumed a maximum of 3-4GB, currently the apache itself consumes 12.30 GB, where the site has virtually zero traffic. A single page can have a CPU consumption of 35-40%. Load is displayed on the screenshoot at the level of 15%, after the restart the server is so low, after which it jumps at over 100%

Screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9GZu.png)

Any ideas, how can it be sensibly limited?

Comment: The most likely scenario is one of those WP blogs is getting a lot of hits. Check your access logs. If it's legit traffic, look into optimizing your WP blogs, including stuff like caching plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are using prefork, prefork usually take more memory, Please check your selected MPM, I think something is mismatched with used MPM settings and your workload and causing CPU spikes.